# Creating a dynamic form with input buttons

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've tried many different methods, and even tried searching on SO. No answer was what I was looking for.

What I want is to have two input buttons that do some things in pure javascript.

Button one: Have it say "Add" when the page loads. When clicked, the value changes to "Cancel." Also, when it's clicked, have it display a form with three fields. When it's clicked again, have the form disappear. One named 'name', the second named 'location', the third named 'type'. I want the user to be able to submit these three things and have them be stored in the code.

Button two: Take the user input from the form and each time the user clicks, it displays all three information values, but have the button act as random generator. Let's say the code has 5 separate entries, I want them to be randomly selected and displayed when the button is clicked.

Like I said, I tried to make this work, but couldn't quite get over the top of where I wanted to go with it. If you want to see my original code, just ask, but I doubt it will be of any assistance.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Added the code.

```js
function GetValue() {
  var myarray = [];
  var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = random;
}
var testObject = {
  'name': BWW,
  'location': "Sesame Street",
  'type': Bar
};

localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');

function change() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("btnAdd1");
  if (elem.value == "Add Spot") {
    elem.value = "Cancel";
  } else elem.value = "Add Spot";

}

window.onload = function() {

  var button = document.getElementById('btnAdd1');

  button.onclick = function show() {
    var div = document.getElementById('order');
    if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
      div.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      div.style.display = 'block';

    }
  };
};
```

```html
<section>
  <input type="button" id="btnChoose" value="Random Spot" onclick="GetValue();" />
  <p id="message"></p>
  <input type="button" id="btnAdd1" value="Add Spot" onclick="change();" />
  <div class="form"></div>
  <form id="order" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name of Resturant" required="required" autocomplete="on" />
    <input type="text" name="type" placeholder="Type of Food" required="required" autocomplete="off" />
    <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Location" required="required" autocomplete="off" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add Spot" />
  </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

The randomizer works, and so does the appear/hide form. Only thing is storing the input and switching the input value.

Comment: Can you go ahead and put your code up? That way we can see your thought process and help with that?

Comment: Sure thing, I'll get it for you.

Comment: Can you use jQuery or no?

Comment: Tim, I prefer not to. Trying to learn from my mistakes in pure JS.

Comment: I'll point out one thing: in your test object you have two items that should be strings: BWW and Bar (unless those things are defined elsewhere)

Comment: Do you want to change the two existing buttons, or create two new buttons?

Comment: James -- changing the same would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's one way to do this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JddvLz). Each form submission is stored as an object in an array. The random button randomly selects an item from the array and displays it below.

HTML:

```
<section>
    <input type="button" id="btnChoose" value="Random Spot" />
    <p id="message"></p>
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd1" value="Add Spot" />
    <div class="form">
    <form id="order" style="display:none;">
        <input id="orderName" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name of Resturant" required="required" autocomplete="on" />
        <input id="orderType" type="text" name="type" placeholder="Type of Food" required="required" autocomplete="off" />
        <input id="orderLocation" type="text" name="location" placeholder="Location" required="required" autocomplete="off" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add Spot" />
    </form>
    </div>
</section>

<div id="randomName"></div>
<div id="randomLocation"></div>
<div id="randomType"></div>
```

JS:

```
var formData = [];
var formSubmission = function(name, location, type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
    this.type = type;
}
var spotName = document.getElementById("orderName"),
    spotLocation = document.getElementById("orderLocation"),
    spotType = document.getElementById("orderType");

var addClick = function() {
    if (this.value === 'Add Spot') {
        this.value = "Cancel";
        document.getElementById('order').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        this.value = 'Add Spot';
        document.getElementById('order').style.display = 'none';
    }
}

document.getElementById("btnAdd1").onclick = addClick;

document.getElementById('order').onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   var submission = new formSubmission(spotName.value, spotLocation.value, spotType.value);
   formData.push(submission);
   submission = '';
    document.getElementById('btnAdd1').value = 'Add Spot';
    document.getElementById('order').style.display = 'none';
    this.reset();
}

var randomValue;
document.getElementById('btnChoose').onclick = function() {
    randomValue = formData[Math.floor(Math.random()*formData.length)];
    document.getElementById('randomName').innerHTML = randomValue.name;
    document.getElementById('randomLocation').innerHTML = randomValue.location;
    document.getElementById('randomType').innerHTML = randomValue.type;
}
```

Comment: Tim, this worked great. One thing: When the page is refreshed, it seems to flush out all the user input and starts over. Was this what was intended from your code?

Comment: @tortuga Well yes, it's only saving it in a variable. If you want to save it in a less temporary way, you'll have to do something like localstorage (if it's user-specific) or through the use of a database (if you want to save across sessions and users).

Answer (score 0):

I was working on something since you first posted, and here is my take on it:

HTML:

```
<section>
    <p id="message">
        <div id="name"></div>
        <div id="location"></div>
        <div id="type"></div>
    </p>
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" onclick="doAdd(this);" />
    <input type="button" id="btnShow" value="Show" onclick="doShow(this);" />
    <div class="form">
        <script id="myRowTemplate" type="text/template">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name of Resturant" required="required" autocomplete="on" onchange="onChanged(this, {{i}})" />
            <input type="text" name="type" placeholder="Type of Food" required="required" autocomplete="off" onchange="onChanged(this, {{i}})" />
            <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Location" required="required" autocomplete="off" onchange="onChanged(this, {{i}})" />
        </script>
        <form id="order" style="display:none;">
            <div id="formItems">
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="Add Spot" onclick="addSpot()" />
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS:

```
function GetValue() {
    if (enteredItems.length) {
        var entry = enteredItems[Math.floor(Math.random() * enteredItems.length)];
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = entry.name;
        document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = entry.location;
        document.getElementById("type").innerHTML = entry.type;
    }
}

function doAdd(elem) {
    switch (elem.value) {
        case "Add":
            document.getElementById('order').style.display = "";
            elem.value = "Cancel";
            break;
        case "Cancel":
            document.getElementById('order').style.display = "none";
            elem.value = "Add";
            break;
    }
}

function doShow(elem) {
    GetValue();
}

function addSpot(index) { // (note: here, index is only for loading for the first time)
    if (index == undefined) index = enteredItems.length;
    var newRowDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newRowDiv.innerHTML = document.getElementById("myRowTemplate").innerHTML.replace(/{{i}}/g, index); // (this updates the template with the entry in the array it belongs)
    if (enteredItems[index] == undefined)
        enteredItems[index] = { name: "", location: "", type: "" }; // (create new entry)
    else {debugger;
        newRowDiv.children[0].value = enteredItems[index].name;
        newRowDiv.children[1].value = enteredItems[index].location;
        newRowDiv.children[2].value = enteredItems[index].type;
    }
    document.getElementById("formItems").appendChild(newRowDiv);
}

function onChanged(elem, index) {
    enteredItems[index][elem.name] = elem.value;
    localStorage.setItem('enteredItems', JSON.stringify(enteredItems)); // (save each time
}

// update the UI with any saved items 

var enteredItems = [];

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('enteredItems');

    if (retrievedObject)
        enteredItems =  retrievedObject = JSON.parse(retrievedObject);

    for (var i = 0; i < enteredItems.length; ++i)
        addSpot(i);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k1vp8dqn/

It took me a bit longer because I noticed you were trying to save the items, so I whipped up something that you can play with to suit your needs.